# ncurses- KEY_ENTER is fail

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

I've been trying to teach myself ncurses and I'm loving it so far. However, I'm trying to write a small little text editor like pico or nano.  I've got it set up fairly well so far. I created a function to map the keys. No matter what I do I can not get a response from `KEY_ENTER`. Whenever I press it it just goes to the beginning of the currently line that I'm on. I've tried using raw(); and using 13 instead of `KEY_ENTER` no luck. All the other keys respond as expected. I would appreciate any advice. I've been staring at this trying to make it work forever.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

// gcc keymaps.c -lncurses -o keymaps
int main(){
    int ch;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);

    while (ch = getch()) {
      switch(ch){
         case KEY_UP:
              addstr("Up\n");
              break;
          case KEY_LEFT:
              addstr("Left\n");
              break;
          case KEY_RIGHT:
              addstr("Right\n");
              break;
          case KEY_BACKSPACE:
              addstr("Backspace\n");
              break;
          case KEY_ENTER:
              addstr("You pressed Enter\n");
          default:
            printw ("%u\n", ch);
            break;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The likely problem is user confusion between the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the regular keyboard versus the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the numeric keypad.  Those *could* both send a control/M (13), but not necessarily.  The terminal description and `KEY_ENTER` refer to the numeric keypad.

The ncurses manual page for `getch` explains the behavior in the [*NOTES*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h2-NOTES):

> Some  keys  may be the same as commonly used control keys,
>   e.g., **`KEY_ENTER`**  versus  control/M,  `KEY_BACKSPACE`  versus
>   control/H.  Some curses implementations may differ according to whether they treat  these  control  keys  specially
>   (and  ignore  the  terminfo),  or use the terminfo definitions.  Ncurses uses the terminfo definition.  If it  says
>   that  **`KEY_ENTER`**  is control/M, getch will return **`KEY_ENTER`**
>   when you press control/M.
>
> Generally, **`KEY_ENTER`** denotes the character(s) sent by  the
>   *Enter* key on the **numeric keypad**:
>
> - the terminal description lists the most useful keys,
> - the  *Enter* key on the **regular keyboard** is already handled by the standard ASCII characters for carriage-return and line-feed,
> - depending  on  whether `nl` or `nonl` was called, pressing
>     "Enter" on the regular keyboard may  return  either  a
>     carriage-return or line-feed, and finally
> - "Enter  or  send" is the standard description for this
>     key.

Line-feed, by the way, is a 10.  But in C, it is usually shown as `'\n'` (and carriage return as `'\r'`).

Answer (score 10):

Try 10 as ASCII value ... worked for me on ncurses.Also please update the actual code because this code that you put is wrong by syntax.

Answer (score 3):

From the [PDCurses documentation](http://pdcurses.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdcurses/PDCurses/curses.h?view=markup):

```
#define KEY_ENTER 0x157 /* enter or send (unreliable) */
```

Try calling `nonl()` after `raw()`.

> The nl and nonl routines control whether the underlying display device translates the return key into newline on input, and whether it translates newline into return and line-feed on output (in either case, the call addch('\n') does the equivalent of return and line feed on the virtual screen). Initially, these translations do occur. If you disable them using nonl, curses will be able to make better use of the line-feed capability, resulting in faster cursor motion. Also, curses will then be able to detect the return key.

Comment: hmm.... seems like that should have worked but it didn't. I'm going to keep toying with it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I got the same `KEY_ENTER` problem recently, and I fixed it by replacing `KEY_ENTER` with 10 or **\n**, which is ASCII new line.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main() {
    initscr();  /* init ncurses */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   /* get keyboard input */
    addstr("Press enter to exit.\n");
    while (10 != getch()) {}    /* 10 == enter */
    endwin();   /* end ncurses */
    return 0;
}
```