# How to check for ENTER key press in curses. curses.KEY_ENTER not working

Tags: python, curses

I am trying to get user input in curses (python), and for some reason it cannot detect when I press the ENTER key.

```
while True:
        key = stdscr.getkey()
        if key == curses.KEY_ENTER:
            TASK += 1
            break
        elif key.lower() == 'q':
            quit(stdscr)
            break
```

the `if` part is not working and the `elif` part is working fine.

Comment: This answers your question: [Interpreting "ENTER" keypress in stdscr (curses module in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252733/interpreting-enter-keypress-in-stdscr-curses-module-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`curses.KEY_ENTER` would be the numeric-keypad <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> key

- if curses `keypad` mode is enabled **and**
- if the terminal description has the corresponding code **and**
- if the terminal actually sends what the terminal description says. (Keypad coverage on some terminal emulators is an area for improvement).

It's not related to the <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> key on the main keyboard.

You'll get better results if you add a comparison for `\n` and `\r` (this is probably a duplicate).